# How to match only odd occurrences of a character at the end of the line using grep

Tags: regex, grep

For example, I'm matching odd occurrences of 'a'.
So "helloaaa" should match while "helloaaaa" should not match.

I've also tried "(aa)*a$" with and without -E option on bash.

Comment: So what is your problem? You forget to actually ask a question...

Comment: I need a regular expression which will match strings which have odd number of a at the end of the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `helloaaaa` matches because of the last three `a`s:

```
helloaaaa
      ===
```

To avoid this you need to make sure that the previous character is not an `a`:

```
grep -E '[^a](aa)*a$' filename
```

Here I'm assuming that the line isn't entirely `a`s. If the entire line can be `a`s then you can use this regular expression instead:

```
grep -E '(^|[^a])(aa)*a$' filename
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me on all the examples I tested. Can you provide an example for which it does not work, what you see for this example and what you expected to see?

Comment: I did try this expression. The problem was I was using double quotes instead of single quotes. Thanks for the quick response.